# Input type file gets removed if we click cancel when the fileupload Popup is coming

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

For reproducing the issue,
step 1 : select the input type file.
Step 2 : when popup comes select any file.
step 3 : again click input type file.
Step 4 : cancel the popup for selecting the file.
In Google Chrome, the files which we had added previously gets removed.
But in Firefox, the files will remain.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="" autocomplete="off" className="inp-file" onChange={uploadFile} multiple />
```

JS:

```
const uploadFile = async (e) => {
    sidefile = e.target.files
    const count = sidefile.length
    setFileCountState(count)
    if (count === 1) {
      setUploadStatus(`${count} File Uploaded`)
    } else {
      setUploadStatus(`${count} Files Uploaded`)
    }
    setRunButtonStatus(false)
  }
```

My project is in Reactjs.
Please give me a solution or please tell me if I had done something wrong.

Comment: This is by design of the browser. There's nothing you can do about it. What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: I need to have the files even if we click the cancel button. Just how it works in firefox. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how Chrome works. To recreate the Firefox behaviour you'd need create your own control which takes the selected `File` object from the input and stores it outside of the control. Then you can manually list the selected files in the UI and let people remove them. You will also need to change the way the form submits data so that you can encode this binary file in to the request. That's not a trivial change.